# pandas_profiling - I am having trouble reading the correlation table

Tags: pandas

My data has five numeric columns:

[image]

And this is what pandas_profiling generates as the correlation matrix. I can't understand it. I see that red means 1.0. But why does each pair of variables seem to have either two or four colored squares? Are the axis labels off? Am I not aware of the way these charts are used?

[image]

Comment: Looks like poor design to me. In this particular case I see no gain over a correlation matrix with the values shown.

Comment: yeah but still not clear what it even means. That's my question.

Comment: The only way I can make sense of this is that the top and bottom rows are narrower (one unit high) than those  between (two units high). I can't imagine a statistical or graphical reason for that, so -- as a occasional programmer, although not in this software at all -- I have to guess that to be a coding error.